# as3 datagrid last entry move first row

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid

I'm using simple code for datagrid, I need to last entry move to the first row

```
//simple data entry 
import fl.controls.DataGrid; 
import fl.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn; 
import fl.data.DataProvider; 
import fl.events.DataGridEvent; 
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider(); 
var myDataGrid:DataGrid = new DataGrid(); 
myDataGrid.addColumn("col1");
myDataGrid.addColumn("col2"); 
myDataGrid.addColumn("col3");
myDataGrid.dataProvider = dp; 
myDataGrid.setSize(300, 200);
myDataGrid.move(10, 10); 
addChild(myDataGrid);

btn.buttonMode = true; 
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, yap);

function yap(event:MouseEvent) {    
    dp.addItem({col1:t1.text,col2:t2.text, col3:t3.text});  
    t1.text = "";   
    t2.text = "";   
    t3.text = ""; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an element to the start of the `DataProvider` by using `dp.addItemAt(yourItemHere,0)` over `dp.addItem()`.

This should add your item to the top of the grid